# Таблица умножения в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогоите сделать таблицу умножения в python. Таблица вида:
[image: При вводе 5]

*При вводе 5*

Пытаюсь сделать двойной цикл:

*1)Для строки*

*2)Для столбца*

Вот до чего я пока додумался... (Начинающий)

```
s1=int(input())
for i in range(s1):
    print(i+1,end='\t')
    for g in range(i):
        print((g+1)*i)
        break
```

Вывод

```
1   2   1
3   2
4   3
5   4
```

Буду очень благодарен любой помощи!

Comment: `range` в вашем случае первым числом всегда возвращает ноль, вот оттуда ноль в переменных `i` и `g` и берётся

Comment: Почему он возвращает ноль, если в `print` я написал `i+1` ?

Comment: а в print(g*i)  - не написано +1

Comment: Ааа, точно! Но первая строка всё равно не выводит все пять чисел

Comment: После вашей правки фраза «Не понимаю откуда берутся нули» стала бессмысленной

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
for i in range(1, s1+1):
     print(*range(i, i*s1+1, i), sep='\t')
```

Вывод:

```
1       2       3       4       5
2       4       6       8       10
3       6       9       12      15
4       8       12      16      20
5       10      15      20      25
```

---

или "простой" вариант:

```
for i in range(1, s1+1):
     for j in range(i, i*s1+1, i):
         print(j, end='\t')
     print()
```

Вывод:

```
1       2       3       4       5
2       4       6       8       10
3       6       9       12      15
4       8       12      16      20
5       10      15      20      25
```

Comment: А что значит In[38] ?

Comment: @coooler, это iPython (интерактивный Python) так помечает ввод (`In [##]`) и вывод (`Out [##]`)

Comment: А можно попроще? Меня тьюторы за такое выгонят. Мы ещё такого не проходили

Comment: @coooler не проходили интерактивную консоль? Валите от таких «тьюторов» подальше

Comment: Тем не менее, @MaxU, всё-таки далеко не все юзают или вообще знают IPython, я бы вам советовал не тащить мусор из него в ответы

Comment: А где можно ознакомиться с этой интерактивное консолью и iphyton'ом ? Есть какие-то хорошие источники?

Comment: @coooler, начните [отсюда](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/tutorial.html)

Comment: @MaxU Благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

```
max_ = int(input())

for row in range(1, max_ + 1):
    for column in range(1, max_ + 1):
        print(row * column, end='\t')
    print()
```

Вам нужно печать *только произведения* и ничего другого. Я изменил имя переменных чтобы был код более понятным.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        print(i * j, " " * (5 - len(str(i * j))), end=" ")
    print("\n", end="")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, 10):
   for j in range(1, 10):
       print(i, '*', j, '=', i * j, end='\t\t')
   print()
```

Простейший вариант

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. в частности, уточните, чем именно ваш ответ отличается от уже существующих.

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for number_1 in numbers:
  for number_2 in numbers:
    print(number_1, '*', number_2, '=', number_1 * number_2)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В исходном вопросе требовалась скорее таблица Пифагора

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(1, 10):
        txt = i * j
        print(f"{i} * {j} = {txt}")
```